# Cant install MySQLdb module Centos 7 Python 3

Tags: python, mysql, module, mysql-python

I have a python code that uses the module mysqldb, I searched a lot and it looks like that module isnt available for python3 anymore, I tried so many solutions until I reached this point, whenever I use `pip3 install mysqlclient` I get this error:

```
    Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dhu9r_pj/mysqlclient_0e2dcd019f494a5a9aba92fe372a86ec/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dhu9r_pj/mysqlclient_0e2dcd019f494a5a9aba92fe372a86ec/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-613c27qp
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-dhu9r_pj/mysqlclient_0e2dcd019f494a5a9aba92fe372a86ec/
```

https://pastebin.com/WKXBkFWB

Comment: Please post your output as text. Screenshots of text can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: pastebin is no image it is a text site

Comment: pastepin link added

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing `mysql-devel python3-devel` packages

You need them as you are building from source. Prebuilt packages for 2.1.0 are available for CPython 3.7-3.10

You could try to `pip install mysqlclient==2.0` for CPython 3.6, or `pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12` for 3.5

Comment: I made sure I have both packages installed, python3-devel-3.6.8 and MariaDB-devel-10.4.22
The python version is 3.6.8, I tried both mysqlclient 2.0 and 1.3.12, same error.
Thanks!!